# Tungsten Replicator not working for redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, tungsten-replicator

I am trying to install the tungsten replicator on single host.My source data source is MYSQL and destination is redshift.
I am following http://docs.continuent.com/tungsten-replicator-4.0/deployment-redshift-installation.html  to setup the replicators.
steps

1) default configuration.

```
./tools/tpm configure defaults --reset
./tools/tpm configure alpha \
--install-directory=/opt/continuent \
--enable-heterogenous-service=true \
--members=localhost,localhost \
--master=localhost \
--java-user-timezone=GMT \
--java-file-encoding=UTF8
```

2) Master configuration (MYSQL)

```
./tools/tpm configure alpha --hosts=localhost \
--replication-user=<> \
--replication-password=<> \
--property=replicator.filter.pkey.addColumnsToDeletes=true \
--property=replicator.filter.pkey.addPkeyToInserts=true
```

3) Slave configuration (Redshift)

```
./tools/tpm configure alpha --hosts=localhost \
--replication-host=redshift.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com \
--replication-user=awsRedshiftUser \
--replication-password=awsRedshiftPass \
--datasource-type=redshift \
--batch-enabled=true \
--batch-load-template=redshift \
--redshift-dbname=dev \
--svc-applier-filters=dropstatementdata \
--svc-applier-block-commit-interval=10m \
--svc-applier-block-commit-size=5
```

Then when running tpm install alpha it gives me the error.

```
ERROR >> Replication service localhost - alpha: Replication service  allowed pipelines
ERROR >> > Message: Unable to extract from redshift@redshift.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439 (WITH PASSWORD)
ERROR >> > Prompt Class: ReplicationServicePipelines
DEBUG >> Call ConfigureDeploymentHandler:cleanup for config 0 on localhost
DEBUG >> [INSIDE THREAD] Call ConfigureDeploymentHandler:cleanup for config 0 on localhost
```

Answer (score 2):

f you try to install both replicators on the same host you also have to specify the correct thl ports and the role of the replicator. See [Docu](https://docs.continuent.com/tungsten-replicator-4.0/deployment-multiple-replicators.html)

Try adding this to your applier:

```
--master-thl-host=localhost
--master-thl-port=2112
--master=localhost
--members=localhost
--rmi-port=10002
--role=slave
--thl-port=2113
--skip-validation-check=HostsFileCheck
```